# Using R to Assign Treatments to Groups

Tags: r

We have seven exposures and 24 groups. We would like to randomly assign five of the seven exposures to groups while also ensuring that we end up with a consistent count for each exposure, meaning that each exposure ends up being exposed about the same number of times. I have written some code that does this but I cannot control how many times each exposure is shown. For example:

```
exposures <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
groups <- c(1:24)

table <- c()

for (i in 1:24){
  draw <-   sample(exposures, size=5, replace=F)
  table <- rbind(table, draw)   
} 

table(table)
```

So the counts end up somewhat close but is there something I can do to ensure a  minimum for each exposure? Thanks!

*EDIT* Also, we need each exposure to appear only once per group.

Comment: This is literally impossible if the number of groups times number of exposures per group is not an integer multiple of the total number of exposures (which it isn't in this case... 120 is not an integer multiple of 7)

Comment: @Bridgeburners I see "about the same number of times" and "ensure a minimum for each".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to think of it in terms of the two exposures that aren't used, rather than the five that are. Let's limit the number of times an exposure can be excluded:

```
draw_exc <- function(exposures,nexp,ng,max_excluded = 10){

  nexc    <- length(exposures)-nexp

  exp_rem <- exposures
  exc     <- matrix(,ng,nexc)
  for (i in 1:ng){
    pool    <- combn(exp_rem,nexc)
    draw    <- pool[,sample(1:ncol(pool), 1)]

    exc[i,] <- draw

    tab     <- table(exc)
    exp_rem <- setdiff(exp_rem, names(tab[tab > max_excluded]) )   
  } 
  exc
}
```

Here's an illustration:

```
set.seed(1)
exc        <- draw_exc(exposures,5,24,10)
assignment <- apply(exc,1,function(x) setdiff(exposures,x))

table(exc)
# exc
#  A  B  C  D  E  F  G 
#  7  4  6  6  8 10  7 

table(assignment)
# assignment
#  A  B  C  D  E  F  G 
# 17 20 18 18 16 14 17
```

So, with 24 groups, the maximum number of exclusions equals 24 minus the minimum  number of appearances. This loop is not efficient, but it seems to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks Frank! This was most helpful.